# How to work on files in build directory?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to read/modify files in build directory, i.e.:

```
    std::ifstream file( "config.conf" );
```

This works fine as long as I run the program from inside the build directory (./executable)
but when trying to launch it through /home/user/build/executable I get "segmentation fault"

This doesn't happen when I use the full directory

```
    std::ifstream file( "/home/user/build/config.conf" );
```

but I need it to be dynamic.

What is the right way of acheiving this?
I'm using QT Creator and I'm including the files in the project.

Comment: This will not solve the path issue however maybe you want to use QSettings for a conf file.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ifstream file(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/config.conf"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted. Works after converting to const char:
`std::ifstream file(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/config.conf").toUtf8().constData() );`

Comment: `.toUtf8` isn't portable, unfortunately. On Windows you'd need `.utf16` (note the different spelling).

Comment: Use `QString::toStdString()` to convert to an `std::string` and use `std::ifstream`'s constructor taking an `std::string` rather than a const char array (not sure if that takes care of the portability, but it's shorter).

Answer (score 0):

The correct and I'd say most Qt-approved way of doing this would be to add your file to a .qrc resource file and embed that file into your application directly, then you can access it from inside the application (no matter from where you launch the executable) simply by prefixing its path with a colon.

More about this here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html

Comment: This works for reading files, but (from what I've read) it's impossible to write to resource files at run time.